# How to integrate Mozilla Sops with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mozilla-sops

I want to integrate sops with Kubernetes to decrypt the K8's resource. We are using Helm chart for deployment through Jenkins CICD. Our Kubernetes charts is placed on Git where we run a scripts to deploy with helm.

I tried it manually but want to automate with Kubernetes runtime